# Is there a name for the value $x$ such that $f(x)$ is maximum?

Tags: terminology

Obviously, $f(x)$ is called the "maximum value" or simply "maximum", but what is $x$ called? The maximizer?

Additionally, what if $f(x)$ is minimum or simply an extremum?

Comment: "maximizer" sounds fine to me.

Comment: The Maximizer strikes again...

Comment: Sometimes known as the $\arg \max$, albeit this is usually the set of parameters that attain the maximum.

Comment: "Parameter that attains the maximum" is also a good term for the case that learning potentially new terminology is not the scope of a paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's often called the 'arg max' ('argument maximum'; similarly 'arg min'):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Comment: Thanks. This seems well accepted enough.

Comment: Technically, arg max is the _set_ of maximizers. This is true even if the maximizer $x^*$ is unique, that is, if $f(x^*)>f(x)$ for any $x\neq x^*$ in the domain of $f$. In this case, you could call $x^*$ the maximizer and $\{x^*\}$ the arg max. Despite the abuse of terminology, however, $x^*$ is often simply called the arg max anyway.